# How to locate elements in another view in protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

So I have a page that has a frame, and in that frame another view. How do locate the elements inside the view and test it? I know how to access that frame, just locating the view after that is pretty confusing.

my problem looks similar to this: [How do I locate elements in protractor that are in other views and are not visible when viewing page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811895/how-do-i-locate-elements-in-protractor-that-are-in-other-views-and-are-not-visib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you switch to the frame, locate the elements in the view the same way you do it in the main content of the document:

```
browser.switchTo().frame("frame_name_or_id");
var view = element(by.css("div[ui-view]"));
view.element(by.id("some_element_id")).click();
```

Comment: Hi. so I can locate the view now, when when I try to click an element inside it, it says 'Cannot read property "click" of undefined'.

Comment: @123457890 I suspect there is a problem in your actual code. Could you show what are you executing?

Comment: this is working. typo error on my end that's why it didn't work! thank you so much! :D